# What event to listen on accordion panel change in extjs?

Tags: events, extjs, accordion

What event to listen when a accordion panel is clicked and becomes visible? Any code example will be great help. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In ExtJS, Accordion is a layout which we will be using on Panel. Here is a sample example from sencha docs.(As you didn't mention version of ExtJS, I am assuming v4.0) :

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
title: 'Accordion Layout',
width: 300,
height: 300,
layout:'accordion',
defaults: {
    // applied to each contained panel
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
},
layoutConfig: {
    // layout-specific configs go here
    titleCollapse: false,
    animate: true,
    activeOnTop: true
},
items: [{
    title: 'Panel 1',
    html: 'Panel content!',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(thisCmp, eOpts) //(Ext.Component this, Object eOpts ) {
            // do what you want to do here
        }
    }
},{
    title: 'Panel 2',
    html: 'Panel content!'
},{
    title: 'Panel 3',
    html: 'Panel content!'
}],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

All events associated with Panel are applicable here. Check out usage of these events [here on sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel).

Comment: There's no event handling in the answer, which the original question seems to request.  I think that's the issue.

Comment: @ruffin : I gave this ex. to tell that Accordian layout is a panel and all events associated with 'panel' can be considered for Accordian Panel. Read my comment to George's answer.

Comment: Gotcha; didn't realize George had continued the question below. Just trying to answer your question from the 19th. Looks good; thx.

Comment: why are answers criticized so much? Nandkumar pointed in the right correction, might not be the best or full answer, but that's why you can give another answer if you have a better one. Criticizing just demotivates to help eachother.

Answer (score 8):

expand; see:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-event-expand

Here is a working code snippet of mine you could substitute for the items in the example code above, that is working for me:

```
items: [{
    title: 'Watch Folder',
    html: 'Watch Folder'
},{
    title: 'Saved Search',
    html: 'Saved Search',
    listeners: {
        expand: function() {
            console.log('saved-search/expand');
        }
    }
},{
    title: 'Search History',
    html: 'Search History'
},{
    title: 'Special',
    html: 'Special'
}]
```

Comment: thanks George, my intention was to take him in direction to the answer. I just told him(who questioned), events for panel are also applicable for Accordian panel. He might have figured out the answer and marked it correct.

Comment: Sorry if I was harsh but I found your answer via Google and it did not solve my problem -- I had to go figure it out anyway.  Your answer was probably better as a comment, such as, have you read the docs located here?  Otherwise, answers should truly solve the OP's question, so that when the answers are found through googling, they subsequently help others.