# How do we set an onExpand event in a cfLayout accordion

Tags: javascript, extjs, coldfusion

We're using CFLayout to create a tab structure in our web application.  After creation of that layout we call this function:

```
mytabs = ColdFusion.Layout.getTabLayout("#attributes.cflayoutName#");
mytabs.on('tabchange',
    function(tablayout,tab) {           
        var tabtitle = tab.title;
        alert(tabtitle); // Actual code does various useful 'stuff' here.
    }
);
```

That piece of code works very well, and the alert will show each time the user clicks on a tab.

The problem is that we are now trying to do the same thing with a CFLayout type of "accordion", and I cannot get an event to fire when the user switches which accordion pane they are looking at.  We've tried leaving the above as is, as well as changing the "tabchange" attribute to "expand", "beforeexpand", "activate", and "collapse".

For this testing I'm using the following simple JS function to avoid issues arising from the JS within the onchange event:

```
mytabs = ColdFusion.Layout.getAccordionLayout("#attributes.cflayoutName#");
mytabs.on('expand',
    function(tablayout,tab) {
        console.log('test');
    }
);
```

We do not receive any errors.  Nothing is logged to the console at all.  I've tried replacing the console.log to an alert to rule out any problems with that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the Ext library documentation to be very helpful with finding a solution to this problem:  [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-getComponent).

The Ext library has a getComponent method that allows you to reference the accordion layout panel that you are trying to add the expand event to.  Once you have this, you can use the "on" method you are using above to assign the expand event to each panel individually.

```
for (x=1; x<accordionLayoutArray.length; x++) {
        mytabs.getComponent(accordionPanelName).on('expand',
            function(tab) { ... });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*This became too long for a comment so adding as an answer*

After some Google searches I found what I think are some related posts.  It appears as though the accordion in Ext JS does not have the same events as the tab.  Instead you need to add a listener in order to catch the expanding.

[See this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?49756-Accordion-events) - *in case something happens to that page here is the relevant piece:*

> You'd need to listen to the expand event of the child panels in the accordion, you could do something like:
>
> Code:
>
> ```
>     myAccordion.add(myFunc('myTitle'));
>     function myFunc(title)
>     {
>        return new Ext.Panel(
>        {
>           title: title,
>           listeners: { 'expand': {fn: something, scope: foo}}
>        }
>        );
>     }
> ```

[And I also found another similar post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572167/what-event-to-listen-on-accordion-panel-change-in-extjs) - see both answers

Once you know that the accordion needs a listener you can find a number of results on Google.  Such as [How do I attach an event handler to a panel in extJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225389/how-do-i-attach-an-event-handler-to-a-panel-in-extjs)

[This Google search will give you lots of examples.](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&newwindow=1&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=extjs+accordion+listeners&oq=extjs+accordion+listeners&gs_l=hp.12..35i39.1217.1217.0.3536.1.1.0.0.0.0.95.95.1.1.0.les%3Bcqn%2Ccconf%3D1-2%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Crate_low%3D0-035%2Crate_high%3D0-035%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D2%2Cignore_bad_origquery%3Dtrue%2Conetoken%3Dfalse..0.0...1c.1.kaFvx5_olfY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.b2I&fp=fcc13bb106db125&biw=1012&bih=918)

Hope that helps.

Comment: to enforce your answer, my understanding of the docs is that the tabchange event triggers on any tab change where the panel expand event is specific to a certain panel.

Comment: Thank you; that's very helpful.  I'm trying to read through and understand this better now, but virtually all of the examples I come across show how to add a listener when defining the accordion.  However, since ColdFusion does the defining, I need to add the listener programatically after the fact.  Do you know where I could find code examples on how to do that?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not have code examples for you.  I would start by viewing the source code that is being generated by ColdFusion.  In your browser of choice, use the 'view source' option.  That should tell you how ColdFusion is defining the accordion.